# Simple rewrite example, mod_rewrite 404 issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

`AllowOverride` is set to `All` and `mod_write` is loaded and working (for example if I type some random data in `.htaccess`, I get a 500 error), however it's not doing the rewrite, and hence, I get a 404. Why?

htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule api/(.*)$ api/api.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Tree

```
/srv/www/htdocs/
├── api
│   ├── api.php
│   ├── .htaccess
│   └── index.php
```

Directory conf

```
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs">
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    Options None
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    AllowOverride All
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    <IfModule !mod_access_compat.c>
            Require all granted
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_access_compat.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

An example URL: `http://localhost/api/11122233A`

There is no `error_log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.htaccess` is in `api` directory, use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) api.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```